# stdout and stderr

Tags: bash

I want to get stderr and stdout

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value of `number` in each iteration. Either use `+=`

```
for i in $(seq $1 $2); do
  number+=$(java Input $i 2>&1)
done
```

or invert the structure, putting the loop inside the command substitution instead of the other way around.

```
number=$(for i in $(seq $1 $2); do java Input $i; done 2>&1)
```

Comment: Do you mean `number+=$(...)` in the first example (so a string append), or is the intent that `number` be an array?

Comment: I forgot the `$`.

Comment: It print error:  syntax error near unexpected token ‘java’            $number+=$(java Input $i 2>&1)

Comment: Is there something I missed?

Comment: Drop the `$` immeditely preceding `number`; the left-hand side of `+=` is the name of the variable to update.